# How to correctly use fwrite?

Tags: c

So I have a char* called bufptr that is of size 512. Within the first couple of spots is the name of the file that I will be reading from and everything else after that is data.

ex. `char* bufptr = {'f', 'o', 'o', '.', 'c', '\0', ...}`

I did not initialize it like that but that is the general idea

After this I store the name of the file into a different file using strcpy

ex.

```
auto int i = 0;
while(*bufptr != '\0')
{
    fname[i++] = *bufptr;
    bufptr++;
}
bufptr++;
```

After that, I open up the file

What I am having problems with is the fwrite portion.

I tried writing `fwrite(bufptr, 1, 512 - strlen(destString), fp)`

but instead of

```
// ============================================================================
// File: fcclient.c (Fall 2017)
// ============================================================================
```

I got `þ================================================`

How would I correctly call fwrite so that I don't run into this issue or is it because I am not skipping over the null? Or does string have something before or after the null?

**edit**:
I added a loop to check over bufptr and got this as the output

```
fcclient.c▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒id▒.N=▒C▒h▒▒▒.8▒▒l▒ ▒ ▒▒▒`▒ ▒P▒▒▒H▒
▒`▒djd▒▒dd▒▒@▒
▒@▒(▒d▒p▒▒jd▒▒▒▒▒Бd▒=======================================================================
// File: fcclient.c (Fall 2017)
// ============================================================================
// This program is a file transfer client. The user at the keyboard is pread a total of 1 bytes
```

this was the loop I used

```
auto int t = 0;
for(; t < 512; t+=)
   if(*(bufptr + t) != '\0')
     printf("%c", *(bufptr + t));
```

Here is the server code

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <netinet/in.h>
#include    <sys/socket.h>

// prototypes
int     CopyFile(int  src_sock);

// defined constants
#define BUFLEN              512
#define SERVER_PORT         50004 
#define TRUE                1
#define FALSE               0

// function prototypes
int     CopyFile(int  src_sock);




int     main(void)
{
    auto    char                buf[BUFLEN];       // local buffer
    auto    socklen_t           client_addr_size;  // used for call to accept
    auto    int                 client_socket;     // used for call to accept
    auto    int                 server_socket;     // used for call to socket
    auto    struct sockaddr_in  client_address;    // used for call to accept
    auto    struct sockaddr_in  server_address;    // used for call to bind

    // greet the user
    puts("Welcome to fcserver!");
    puts("Waiting to recieve file from client...");

    // create a socket for the server
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // prepare the socket address structure for the server
    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    // bind the server socket to an address, using the address structure
    if(bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)))
    {
        perror("server -- bind failed");
    }

    // put the server socket into a listening state
    if(listen(server_socket, 5))
    {   
        perror("server -- bind failed");
    }

    // let stdout know the server is waiting for a connection
    puts("server waiting...");

    // wait for an actual client connection (this will block)
    client_addr_size = sizeof(server_address);
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, &client_addr_size);


    CopyFile(client_socket);

    // close the client and server sockets
    close(client_socket);
    close(server_socket);

    return 0;

}  // end of "main"





int     CopyFile(int  src_sock)
{
    auto    char                        buf[BUFLEN];
    auto    char                        *bufptr;
    auto    char                        fname[BUFLEN];
    auto    FILE*                       fptr;
    auto    int                         num_client_bytes;
    auto    unsigned long               total_bytes = 0;



    if(-1 == (num_client_bytes = recv(src_sock, bufptr, BUFLEN, 0)))
        perror("server -- recv failed");


    strcpy(fname, bufptr);;
    auto int t = 0;
    for(; t< num_client_bytes; t++)
    {
        if(*(bufptr + t) != '\0')
            printf("%c", *(bufptr + t));
    }


    fptr = fopen(fname, "w");


    auto  int i = strlen(fname) +1;
    bufptr += i;
    total_bytes = fwrite(bufptr, sizeof(bufptr), 1, fptr);
    printf("read a total of %lu bytes \n", total_bytes);


    // loop and read the rest of the file from the client
    do  {

        if(num_client_bytes == 0)
            break;


        printf("read a total of %d bytes \n", num_client_bytes);


        total_bytes += fwrite(buf, 1, num_client_bytes, fptr);

        } while (TRUE);



    fclose(fptr);

    printf("there were a total of %lu bytes written \n", total_bytes);

    return TRUE;

}  // end of "CopyFile"
```

Here is the client file

```
  // ============================================================================
// File: fcclient.c (Fall 2017)
// ============================================================================

#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <sys/socket.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <sys/un.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <netinet/in.h>

#define BUFLEN          256
#define SERVER_PORT     50004


int     main(void)
{
    auto    char                buf[BUFLEN];       // general purpose buffer
    auto    int                 server_socket;     // used for server socket
    auto    struct sockaddr_in  server_address;    // used for server address
    auto    char                fname[BUFLEN];     // used for filename
    auto    char                *bufptr;           // used for heap block
    auto    FILE                *fptr;             // used for input file
    auto    int                 result;            // used to check return values
    auto    long                fileSize;          // used to store file size

    // greet the user
    puts("Welcome to fcclient!");

    // get the filename from stdin
    printf("Please enter in the filename: ");
    scanf("%s", fname);

    // open the input file
    fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Sorry there was an error trying to locate the file. Please exit and try again \n");
        return 0;
    }

    // get the size of the file
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(fptr);
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);

    // allocate a buffer to store the file in heap memory
    bufptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * fileSize);

    // create a socket to connect with the server
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // setup a socket address structure to target the server
    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    printf("Currently connecting to server... \n");

    // connect to the server
    if(-1 == connect(server_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)))
        perror("client -- connect failed"); 

    // send the filename to the server (include the NULL!)
    if(-1 == send(server_socket, fname, BUFLEN, 0))
        perror("client -- send failed");

    // read the file into the allocated buffer
    fseek(fptr, sizeof(bufptr),SEEK_SET); 
    if(0 == fread(bufptr, sizeof(bufptr), fileSize, fptr))
    {
        printf("There was an error sorry. \n");
        return 0;
    }

    // send the data to the server
    if(-1 == send(server_socket, bufptr, fileSize, 0))
            perror("client -- send failed");

    // close the input file and the sockets
    fclose(fptr);
    close(server_socket);

    return 0;

}  // end of "main"
```

Comment: Could you maybe post your code where you are doing this?

Comment: @KulaDamian - updated with the link to compiler

Comment: Ok, tell me one thing, what are you trying to accomplish with this line: bufptr += strlen(destString)

Comment: `fwrite` is already implemented, so you might wanna change the title.

Comment: @KulaDamian - I am trying to move the base address of bufptr

Comment: Please do not post links to off-site material.  Post the material in the question.  One reason for this is that the external site may not continue to show the material for the next 5+ years. You need to explain the difference between the two files linked.  You also need to read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  What you link to is not an MCVE.

Comment: Also note that in C there is no reason to ever use the keyword `auto`.  Don't use it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I write auto because my professor will mark me down if I don't. I would love to not write auto

Comment: You should post your code instead of trying to describe it

Comment: Don't write `auto` in the code you post on SO.  It will simply get you negative attention.  Plus it will yea-much harder to spot plagiarism, etc.  Also, your professor has weird (very, very weird) requirements.  I'd be worried about the standard of teaching you are getting.

Comment: Note that an MCVE will have vastly fewer comments.  Yes, it takes effort to create an MCVE.  But not providing an MCVE makes it hard for those who might be willing to help you to see the meat of the code for the noise.  Zero comments might be an exaggeration; label stuff like the file name and the class are definitely not OK on SO; they're pointless noise here, whatever the rules of the submitted code are.

Comment: In the client code, the two lines `fseek(fptr, sizeof(bufptr), SEEK_SET);
    if (0 == fread(bufptr, sizeof(bufptr), fileSize, fptr))` are very curious.  If you're on a 64-bit machine, you skip over the first 8 bytes of the file; on a 32-bit machine, the first 4 bytes.  Then you try to read 8 (or 4) times the size of the file in bytes, which is going to cause confusion at best.  Earlier, you have `if (-1 == send(server_socket, fname, BUFLEN, 0))`; why on earth are you sending the full buffer when the name is much shorter?  Why not use `strlen(fname)` or `strlen(fname+1)`?

Comment: You might also sensibly send the length of the file name so that the server knows how much to read.  If you stick with sending the full length of the `fname` variable, the server must ignore everything after the null byte of the first BUFLEN bytes of data that it reads.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - how would I go about to avoid skipping over the first couple of bytes?

Comment: `fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET)`.  In the server, after you've collected the filename from that first block, you should be ignoring everything else.  It was garbage in the client that sent it; it isn't any better in the server.  Functions like `send()` send exactly what they're told to send; they don't stop at null bytes or anything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler   But when I send it over and ignore the garbage I am missing a few lines from the beginning of file that was supposed to be sent over

Comment: Given that `bufptr` is uninitialized in `CopyFile()` in the server when you read the name, you're very (un)lucky that the program didn't simply crash.

Answer (score 2):

`bufptr` is not pointing to the content of the buffer,Because of `bufptr += strlen(destString)` , Its pointing to the location next to the content. Update the value of `bufptr` to point to the content you actually want to write.

Comment: I thought that bufptr += strlen(destString) already moves the base location to after the null

Comment: No, it wont. You are asking `strcpy` to copy charcater at a location pointed by one pointer (as a source) to the location pointed by another(as a desination), there is no pointer updation happening.

Comment: I made an edit and used a while loop instead to get the name of the file and update the value of bufptr but I am still getting an error when it writes it out

Comment: Do not update the `bufptr`. Leave it as it is. You are moving the pointer to some junk, which is exactly what you seeing in the file it written to.

Comment: would I still write fwrite(bufptr, 1, 512 - strlen(destString), fp) or would I write fwrite(bufptr, 1, 512, fp)

Comment: `fwrite(bufptr, 1,strlen(bufptr), fp)` will do the job

Comment: @JasonPham Please do not edit qour code after you got answers. This makes it terribly hard to follow what is obsolete or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are two sets of problems in the code (some of them diagnosed in comments made to question).  First, you write a full length buffer even though it contains mostly junk, and then you try to interpret that as part of the file, but it isn't.  And second, you're playing with an uninitialized variable in the client file copy code — you're (un)lucky it didn't crash.

This code works.

#### `fcserver.c`

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <netinet/in.h>
#include    <sys/socket.h>

#define BUFLEN              512
#define SERVER_PORT         50004

void    CopyFile(int src_sock);

int     main(void)
{
    socklen_t client_addr_size;
    int client_socket;
    int server_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;

    puts("Welcome to fcserver!");
    puts("Waiting to recieve file from client...");

    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)))
    {
        perror("server -- bind failed");
    }

    if (listen(server_socket, 5))
    {
        perror("server -- bind failed");
    }

    puts("server waiting...");

    client_addr_size = sizeof(server_address);
    client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, &client_addr_size);

    CopyFile(client_socket);

    close(client_socket);
    close(server_socket);

    return 0;
}

void     CopyFile(int src_sock)
{
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    char fname[BUFLEN];
    FILE *fptr;
    int num_client_bytes;
    unsigned long total_bytes = 0;

    if (-1 == (num_client_bytes = recv(src_sock, fname, BUFLEN, 0)))
    {
        perror("server -- recv failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("File name: [%s]\n", fname);
    fptr = fopen(fname, "w");
    if (fname == 0)
    {
        perror(fname);
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((num_client_bytes = recv(src_sock, buf, BUFLEN, 0)) > 0)
    {
        printf("read a total of %d bytes\n", num_client_bytes);
        total_bytes += fwrite(buf, 1, num_client_bytes, fptr);
    }

    fclose(fptr);

    printf("there were a total of %lu bytes written\n", total_bytes);
}
```

That's 85 lines, instead of 170-odd lines.

#### `fcclient.c`

```
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <sys/socket.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <sys/un.h>
#include    <unistd.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <netinet/in.h>

#define BUFLEN          256
#define SERVER_PORT     50004

int     main(void)
{
    int server_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    char fname[BUFLEN] = "";
    char                *bufptr;
    FILE                *fptr;
    size_t fileSize;

    puts("Welcome to fcclient!");

    printf("Please enter in the filename: ");
    scanf("%s", fname);

    fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Sorry there was an error trying to locate the file. Please exit and try again \n");
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(fptr);
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);

    bufptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * fileSize);

    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&server_address, 0, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    printf("Currently connecting to server... \n");

    if (-1 == connect(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)))
        perror("client -- connect failed");

    if (-1 == send(server_socket, fname, BUFLEN, 0))
        perror("client -- send failed");

    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if (fileSize != fread(bufptr, sizeof(char), fileSize, fptr))
    {
        printf("There was an error sorry. \n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (-1 == send(server_socket, bufptr, fileSize, 0))
        perror("client -- send failed");

    fclose(fptr);
    close(server_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

That's 68 lines instead of 170-odd lines.

#### Testing

It is crucial to run the server in a different directory from the client, else you could get files truncated.  However, when I used a sub-directory `junk` containing a file `animals19.c` and ran the client in that directory, while the server ran in the parent directory, I got the output:

**server window**

```
$ ./fcserver
Welcome to fcserver!
Waiting to recieve file from client...
server waiting...
File name: [animals19.c]
read a total of 512 bytes
read a total of 292 bytes
there were a total of 804 bytes written
$
```

**client window**

```
$ ../fcclient
Welcome to fcclient!
Please enter in the filename: animals19.c
Currently connecting to server... 
$ ls -l animals19.c ../animals19.c
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  804 Dec 13 00:42 ../animals19.c
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  804 Dec  3 21:54 animals19.c
$ diff animals19.c ../animals19.c
$
```

Oh, and at some point, you should note "i before e except after c" (so it is `receive` and not `recieve`).  You should also note that `perror()` prints an error; it does not exit.  Continuing after using `perror()` is usually wrong.